# Should I disavow hidden links

Tags: seo, pagerank

I'm optimizing the SEO for a friend's website. The original designer has created a bunch of links on websites they operate in order to increase Google Ranking for the new site. However, these links are hidden (incorporated in the  tag or elsewhere out of sight of users).

I know that Google penalises hidden links. But will it also penalise my friend's website in addition to the referring sites? In short, I want to tell Google to disavow these domains but also don't want to blow up my rank.

Comment: It may help to see an example. As well, it would help to know if you can edit the template. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

If you can safely remove the links then remove them, if not you can add the nofollow tag to them and Google won't take them into account.

Comment: It sounds like they can't control the links at all. They were created on other sites by somebody no longer associated with their site.   I don't think that removal or nofollow is possible in this case.